# Java/Groovy/Grails need to generate meaningful test data

Tags: java, grails, groovy, test-data

I have a need to generate meaningful test data programatically using either Java or Groovy (Groovy preferred). The data I need includes First Name, Middle Name, Last Name, Address (City, Postal Code, Country, Street), Phone, Email. It would be great if I could add my own logic to the library to address my custom needs for example data for Credit Card or Bank Account, etc.

Could someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you're asking for help with? e.g. Are you looking for a library? Lists of names? Programming advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Grails you can use the [fixtures](http://www.grails.org/Fixtures+Plugin) and the [build-test-data](http://www.grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) plugin.

The fixtures plugin provides a DSL for creating the test data with specific property values. While the test data plugin will fill in all values that you did not assign explicitly, in such a way that all property values comply to the constraints set.

Comment: I am just wondering if build-test-data generates meaningful data or it puts together random characters. thanks.

Comment: for a property String name it will use the value 'name' as standard. Overrides, e.g. making sure each instance gets a different value for property name, can be done in the DataSource.groovy config file. Have a look at https://bitbucket.org/tednaleid/grails-test-data/wiki/Home for more detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

Try [test-data](http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) plugin. Hope this helps what you want to achieve.